# After configuration two databases on Spring boot, i recive empy answer from query, why?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

I am trying to connect two db to Spring boot project.
When I try to query, I have empty result from DB.

The app is launching properly

When I try querying I receive a `nullpointer exception`

```
public class PGDataBaseConfig {

    @Bean(name = "Pgconfig")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.pgdatasource")
    public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {

        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "PG")
    @Primary
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        return firstDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }



    @Bean(name = "PGem")

    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean pgEntity(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
@Qualifier("PG") DataSource firstDataSource) {

           HashMap<String,String>  map = new HashMap<>();


            map.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
            map.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");


        return builder.dataSource(firstDataSource).packages(".db.Postgress.Model").persistenceUnit("PGDB").properties(map)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "PGtrans")

    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("PGem") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

**Second DB config**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "MSem",basePackages = "sla.db.ms", bootstrapMode = BootstrapMode.DEFAULT)
public class MSDataBaseConfig {

    @Bean(name ="MSConfig" )
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.ms.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties thirdDataSorceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Bean(name = "MS")
    public DataSource thirdDataSource() {
        return thirdDataSorceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "MStrans")

      public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("MSem") EntityManagerFactory 
        entityManagerFactory
      ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
      }
```

Comment: Is it connecting to both DB's properly, did you verify the logs.

Comment: Lucia, nothing, may be need something on, but app start properly